# Grey Screen MapView - ArcGIS with Android

Tags: android, arcgis

I'm trying out the sample HelloWorld application using the ArcGIS with Android SDK. The code compiles fine but there's a grey screen on execution. I've taken a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969498/android-how-to-know-if-mapview-is-properly-loaded) but it doesn't solve my issue.

Here's my source code:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {

    MapView map = null;
    ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer tileLayer;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        tileLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Shaded_Relief/MapServer");
        if(tileLayer.isInitialized() == true)  //if a bad url is provided, this will fail
        {   map.addLayer(tileLayer);  }
        else{
                //if no layer is successfully added, the MapView will not initialize
            Toast layerToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Layer didn't load, MapView won't initialize", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            layerToast.show();
        }

        map.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {
           private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

           public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
               //conditional checks if mapView's status has changed to initialized 
                if (OnStatusChangedListener.STATUS.INITIALIZED == status && source == map) 
                { 
                    Toast mapViewToast = Toast.makeText(HelloWorld.this, "MapView loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    mapViewToast.show();
                }
            }
         });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        map.pause();
 }
    @Override   protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); 
        map.unpause();
    }

}
```

Here's my LogCat:

```
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544): url =http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Shaded_Relief/MapServer
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544): org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):  at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4057ed68; line: 1, column: 2]
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1432)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:521)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:442)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._handleUnexpectedValue(ReaderBasedParser.java:1198)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedParser.java:485)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at com.esri.core.internal.b.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at com.esri.core.internal.b.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at com.esri.core.internal.b.a.e.a(Unknown Source)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at com.esri.core.internal.a.a.m.b(Unknown Source)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at com.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer.initLayer(Unknown Source)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at com.esri.android.map.ags.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer$1.run(Unknown Source)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:444)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
06-18 10:51:21.413: E/ArcGIS(1544):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Can you paste in the source of your HelloWorld app?

Comment: Posted it here. It differs a bit from the original HelloWorld code provided by the ArcGIS SDK, but I attempted to try the code from the question I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot check the tileLayer isInitialized return value right away like that. The layer initialization makes network calls and is done asynchronously.

You need to add it to your MapView first, just like in the original HelloWorld sample code. This will start to initialize the layer. Then you can check the events fired from your OnStatusChangedListener for the layer and/or map initializing.

Comment: I'm getting the same error after changing the code and from what I can tell from LogCat, I might be receiving unexpected return from the URL. However, I'm not sure if that's a result of an error in typing the URL or if there's something up with the ArcGIS server that I'm requesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to check the layer initialization for a particular reason then add it to the MapView without using isInitialized().

If you do need to check that the layer is initialized before you proceed, then you can use an OnStatusChangedListener like with the MapView.  You could then wait until the layer's status changes to INITIALIZED and then add it to the MapView.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    tileLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Shaded_Relief/MapServer");
    tileLayer.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {
        public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
            if (OnStatusChangedListener.STATUS.INITIALIZED == status){
                map.addLayer(tileLayer);  //when layer is initialized add to map
            }
        }
    });

    map.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {
       public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
            if (OnStatusChangedListener.STATUS.INITIALIZED == status ) 
            { /*do something when mapView is initialized*/  }
        }
    });

}
```